# Grouping Related Types of Documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Ok I am totally new to MongoDB and started reading MongoDB Definitive guide book.
I am on page 7 and it says: "Group Related types of Documents together"

I don't get it :( a document is something like

```
{"greetings" , "Hello World"}
```

so what do they mean by that sentence? could you please give me a more detailed example so I can picture it in my head.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A document is actually more like: `{"greetings": "Hello World"}`

In this case, its a very simple document consisting of only a key "greetings", and its value "Hello World". Some languages might call this an associative array, or a hash, or a dictionary. The point of this description is that MongoDB doesn't care what the structure is. Its scheme-free and does not require you to ensure that every document in a collection has the exact same structure. But for efficiency and organizational purposes, you would be inclined to store similar documents in a single collection. Thus, you will end up with very similar documents per collection from purely a design perspective.

A document in MongoDB is more or less like a JSON structure (bson to be specific). It can be of arbitrary depth and you create indexes on selected object levels to facilitate faster searching.

For the most part, just think of mongodb like a fancy object storage, with objects that represent whatever language with which you are familiar. The driver specific to your language will handle the bridge between your native object types, and the bson representation in mongodb. You create objects and store them. Its really not all that different than understanding mysql, but knowing that you don't have to define your table schema. Just start storing whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a document would be more like

{  "Greeting":"Hello World" }

meaning the document contains a greeting (key) and the greeting is "Hello World" (value).
A document can be a very complex set of key value pairs, including values which are arrays, embedded documents, etc.

If you include a bunch of arbitrary documents in the same collection, it will be rather difficult to find them later.  So the recommendation would be to group in a collection documents which have something in common.

A relatable example might be to have a collection which has each document representing a user of the system.   The fields in each document will vary depending on how much information you have on each user, but at the very least you may have an email address, name, etc.  You could then query for all users that satisfy some condition.

Another collection might have companies.  You might have an array of users or user ids as one of the fields in a company document to represent every user who works at a company, or something like that.

I'm not familiar with the particular book you mention, but maybe if you keep plowing ahead it will start to make more sense.  If not I recommend reading some of the pages [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tutorial#Tutorial-DynamicSchema%28%22SchemaFree%22%29) for more examples.